# lambda expression for OR condition in Linq to entity

Tags: linq, lambda, linq-to-entities

I have the following condition.
   VersionNumber == versionID + ".pdf" **OR** VersionNumber == versionID + ".null"

This is not taking this way

```
var versionExisting = entities.Documents.Where(d => d.VersionNumber == versionID + ".pdf" || d => d.VersionNumber == versionID + ".null");
```

Comment: You're specifying d=> twice.  You only need specify it once.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do this:

```
var versionExisting = entities.Documents.Where(d => d.VersionNumber == versionID + ".pdf" || d.VersionNumber == versionID + ".null");
```